# Command like head except instead of showing output by new line, shows output by space

Tags: command

`head` example:

```bash
Desktop:  
 λ df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s7s1  113Gi  8.9Gi  8.6Gi    51%  355384 90345720    0%   /
/dev/disk1s2    113Gi  3.3Gi  8.6Gi    28%    1743 90345720    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s4    113Gi   24Ki  8.6Gi     1%       5 90345720    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s6    113Gi   63Mi  8.6Gi     1%     660 90345720    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s5    113Gi   91Gi  8.6Gi    92%  655534 90345720    1%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s1    113Gi   64Ki  8.6Gi     1%      15 90345720    0%   /Volumes/mnbvcxz    - Data
/dev/disk3s1     58Gi   57Gi  843Mi    99%     209  8636800    0%   /Volumes/Untitled

Desktop:  
 λ df -h | head -n1
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
```

Is there a cmd specifically that will show output of fields by space instead of new line?

A cmd what that will do what this `awk` cmd does:

```bash
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on \ 
| awk -F ' ' '{print$1}'
Filesystem
```

Comment: If that awk command already does what you want, what is it that you need?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a specific command for it, I could do what `head -n<number>` does with `awk`.

Comment: In this context, `awk` will do a much better job than `cut` for you.

Comment: A simple comparison of `cut -d ' ' -f 2` and `awk '{print $2}'` will show otherwise (at least, for your given example input).

Comment: 'nushell' ( a newish linux shell) has builtin features for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annoyingly, there's no standard command that will extract ranges of columns separated by a variable amount of whitespace without mangling the spacing:

- For `cut -d ' ' -f 1-2`, any single space is a delimiter so for instance `" a  b"` is 4 fields: `""`, `a`, `""`, `b`.
- `cut -c 1-4` just cuts characters, not fields
- `awk '{print $1, $2}'` extracts fields separated by any amount of blanks, ignoring leading and trailing ones as that's the special behaviour when `FS=" "` as it is by default, but those fields are output separated by one space character (the default value of `OFS`).

To extract the first `$n` (or up to `$n`) fields, while preserving the whitespace between them, with GNU `grep` or compatible, one approach is to use:

```
n=3
grep -Eo "^(\s*\S+){0,$n}"
```

(beware it discards empty lines)

Now, note that the output of that `df` command doesn't follow a pattern that allows extracting data reliably that way as the field values themselves can contain whitespace. See for instance the `Mounted on` header or some of the mount points. See also how some of the fields are left-aligned and some right-aligned. It's very hard to extract fields in that condition without hardcoding the field widths (and use `cut -c` for instance). It's also why `mlr --pprint cut` can't be used here.

If you can, best is to tell the tool that produces the output to print only the columns you want. For instance, with the GNU implementation of `df`, you can use:

```
df -h --output=source,size,used
```

And if you need to post-process that output, look out for options to output in a parsable format. For `df`, `-P` helps only slightly, `df`'s output is not post-processable reliably.

If on Linux, `findmnt`, `lsblk` and GNU `stat -f` can output the same information as `df` can in a post-processable way (see for instance the `-J` option with [How to process JSON with strings containing invalid UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757832) and `-c` for `stat`)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `cut`.

With your example, that would be `cut -d' ' -f1`.